# Setting a block of html code inside a value

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I'm trying to store a block of html code inside a variable. I'm wondering if i can set it like this

```
set var="html" value="i get this value from a controller ${controllerValue}"
```

Do you guys know any alternatives?

Comment: like what?  can you be more specific?